# No Window Manager and no Networking

Tags: 11.04, unity, networking, ppa, gnome

I'm in a bit of a pickle right now due to a few blunders I made on my Ubuntu install. Currently, I have no window managers (so I'm running from a terminal) and no networking, wired or wireless. Here's the backstory:

I upgraded to 11.04 the other day and decided I didn't like Unity one bit. After a bit of Googling, I discovered that GNOME 3 was available (not realizing it was still a beta) and installed it from a ppa. Despite the beautiful interface, it didn't work out for me, since I had no internet connectivity. When I realized I could no longer even use Unity, I panicked and used apt-get to remove the main GNOME 3 packages in the hopes of reversing the damage.

Instead, this left me with just a terminal. I tried using ppa-purge, but it won't work without internet. I'm relatively sure I can restore Unity if I get wired networking back. So my main question is - any suggestions for fixing it?

Thanks a bunch...I've really gone and done it this time.

Derek

Comment: Can you post the output of `ifconfig` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to get connectivity by running `sudo dhclient eth0` with your network cable plugged in.